# Hey Every Time I wanna run my bot it tells me this error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hey Every Time I wanna run my bot it tells me this error but it runs anyway. I wanna know how can I fix it?

**ERROR:**

```
Unhandled exception in internal background task 'ch_pr'.Traceback (most recent call last):  File "C:\Users\Pekah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\tasks\__init__.py", line 178, in _loop    await self.coro(*args, **kwargs)  File "c:\Users\Pekah\OneDrive\Documents\Projects\rare-bot\bot.py", line 32, in ch_pr    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=f'Rare Bot version: {version} '))  File "C:\Users\Pekah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 1112, in change_presence    await self.ws.change_presence(activity=activity, status=status_str)AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'change_presence'
```

**CODE:**

```py
@tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def ch_pr():
    while True:
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=f'Rare Bot version: {version} '))
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening ,name='-help '))
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening ,name=f'{len(client.guilds)} servers '))
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name='discord.py '))
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening ,name=f'{len(client.users)} users '))
        await asyncio.sleep(5)

ch_pr.start()
```

Comment: You can use [`try`/`except` to handle exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and carry on as normal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`try`/`except` to handle exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and carry on as normal. i.e.

```py
while True:
   try:
      a_function_that_might_error()
   except AttributeError:
      pass #do nothing
```

However, this will catch all AttributeErrors. You'd be better off adjusting your code to ensure that the error doesn't happen, or by getting it to throw a more specific custom error that you can catch.